# Does a field need to be placed within an InfoPath form in order to store a value?

Tags: infopath, column, form

I'm interested in storing a boolean value in a field. However, I don't necessarily want to place the field onto the form.

Can values be stored, changed and used in rules without inserting the field into the flow of the InfoPath document?

Comment: I guess I may be asking if a field can be used more like a variable without placing it into the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can choose what all fields you want to display. You will be accessing the data through the data connection any way.

This is a normal use case, for example we don't want user to update say `EmployeeNumber`.. So in this case we use Conditional Formatting to disable the field. In your case you can either don't add the field to the layout or hide/disable using conditional formatting.

Comment: I don't want the field to display at all. I don't want to place the control into the form. I only want to create the field to use it as a variable without placing it into the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but remember that if you place a field like a textbox in your form it will have a corresponding field in your list. I've set values in textboxes and then set the visibility to hidden, and in my event receivers read it's values and perform some logic and other operations.

I've used infopath for many projects but it's much better to use and extend SharePoint Designer Forms (with css, javascript, etc.) unless you have an explicit requeriment about using infopath, I advise you to change your approach, because it's not gonna have support in future versions of SharePoint.

A good start can be found here:

[Using the JavaScript Object Model in a Content Editor Web Part](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2011/04/14/using-the-javascript-object-model-in-a-content-editor-web-part-kumar-abhishek-verma/)

**EDIT:**

You can do that, add a rule that sets the desired field to the value you want, but remember to use the reference in the "dataFields" section of your Fields Pane (Advanced View).

[image: dataFiels advanced view]

[More info on queryFields Vs. dataFields](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/26704/92969.aspx)

Comment: I do not want to place the field into the form. I just want to create the field so it's available in the Fields Task Pane. But when the form is displayed to the user in the browser I don't want to have to hide the control that is associated with the field. I want my rules to just access the form without it placed into the form itself.